# I have a question about background-image in CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a question about background-image in CSS. I want to design a box of which all parts are displayed as background image except for 1 link and button. I need 3 of such box in one line. I've attached an example picture. I can't figure out the problem and need guidance

[image]

```css
body {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  padding: 0px;
}

#price {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url(https://carevisa.at/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#price::after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.plan {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 2%;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 477px;
  height: 832px;

}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  text-align: center;

}

.btn a {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.IMGbox{
  width: 477px;
  height: 832px;
}
.Readmore{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="price">
  <!--price tab-->
  <div class="plan">
      <a href="http://carevisa.at/readmore/" class="Readmore">More details</a>

    <div class="btn">
      <a href="#">Online application</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please reconsider, unless you're deliberately biased against people using screen readers or other accessibility devices. The writing placed in the background-image is not available to the those who might be blind. Given what you're putting together then, frankly, it's simple enough to do completely in HTML which, with semantic markup, will dramatically widen the audience for your product(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead,

Use absolute positioning to **plan** class. That is,

```
.plan {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

And give width and height to **price** id instead of **plan** class.

```
#price {
  position:relative;
  width: 477px;
  height: 832px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

> **[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/MWyQgJQ)**

```css
body {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  padding: 0px;
}

#price {
  position:relative;
  background-image: url(https://carevisa.at/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 477px;
  height: 832px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#price::after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.plan {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin: 10px 2%;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn a {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.IMGbox{
  width: 477px;
  height: 832px;
}
.Readmore{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="price">
  <!--price tab-->
  <div class="plan">
      <a href="http://carevisa.at/readmore/" class="Readmore">More details</a>

    <div class="btn">
      <a href="#">Online application</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="price">
  <!--price tab-->
  <div class="plan">
      <a href="http://carevisa.at/readmore/" class="Readmore">More details</a>

    <div class="btn">
      <a href="#">Online application</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="price">
  <!--price tab-->
  <div class="plan">
      <a href="http://carevisa.at/readmore/" class="Readmore">More details</a>

    <div class="btn">
      <a href="#">Online application</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```